# How do I fix this simple javascript slideshow stuck on the first slide?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I'm having trouble making this simple slideshow work. I think it has something to do with the javascript, but I'm not that far on my training to understand it yet. Here is the code I placed inside the HTML's body:

```
<script>
    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
    var currentSlide = 0;
    var slideInterval = setInterval(nextSlide,2000);

    function nextSlide(){
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
        currentSlide = (currentSlide+1)%slides.length;
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
}</script>

<div id="deps">
    <ul id="slides">
        <li class="slide showing">Slide 1</li>
        <li class="slide">Slide 2</li>
        <li class="slide">Slide 3</li>
        <li class="slide">Slide 4</li>
        <li class="slide">Slide 5</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I can't figure out the problem since I don't even know how to code in js yet. I simply copied the code from a tutorial online, but, unlike there, my slides are stuck on the first one.

Comment: I don't see any error on your code. Maybe the only thing you need to do is add a CSS: `.slide { opacity: 0 } .showing { opacity: 1 }`

Comment: check f12 developer's console for errors.

Comment: Thank you for the support, guys. I tried the best I could to implement the modifications suggested, but I don't think it went very well. Slide is still stuck on first one.

I got a CSS running too, I didn't post the code because I thought the problem was with the JS. Some of it goes like this...

'''
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s;
    transition: opacity 1s;
'''

Inspectioning the console, I can only figure that unchecking the opacity box makes all slides overlay.

Comment: I know I'm not being very helpful... I'm very new to coding and to StackOverflow  = \
But thank you guys very much for trying to help me!   ^.^

Comment: I suppose you have the example from this or a similar page https://www.sitepoint.com/make-a-simple-javascript-slideshow-without-jquery/ and missed to copy the css or at least some part of it. If I add the css from this page to your example the slider is working fine. I copied it into this Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xv3tqpdc/

Comment: Yes, that was the tutorial I used... I implemented the modifications @codeanjero suggested in the answers below, and it worked! Looking at yours, they seem very similar... I'll get to really understand what happened once my classes start again after quarantine.
Thank you for your aid!

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be your setInterval
instead of calling it like this :

```
setInterval(functionname,2000);
```

try it like this :

```
setInterval(()=>{functionname()},2000);
```

this gives you something like this :

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y8nxwv32/)

also be sure to wrap all your code in a domcontent event listener :

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{ /*your javascript code*/ });
```

This makes sure your html elements are available when you use them in javascript

Comment: Hey! This actually worked!
Thank you very much!!

I didn't realise rightaway the 'jsfiddle' was the actual answer  *facepalm*